# How can I call Servlet from d3.json()

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using d3 for charting some nodes and links between them. For bringing the data, I used a json name link.json and called it like-

```
d3.json("linked.json", function(error, graph) {}
```

It works properly.But the data of that json is not dynamic. To make it dynamic I must call a servlet in the place of calling the json.I can't do this.. please anyone help me....

Answer (score 1):

A URL is a URL. Just replace `linked.json` with the URL to the servlet you want to call (making sure that the servlet returns suitably formatted a JSON response).